# GeoCoordinateWatcher in BackgroundAgent WP 7.5

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, background-agents

I want to ask you, if I understand it. When I create GeoCoordinateWathcer in method OnInvoke of BackgroundAgent like this:

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    _watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High)
                   {
                       MovementThreshold = 100
                   };
    _watcher.PositionChanged += PositionChanged;
    _watcher.Start();
}
```

and I move more than 100m and Task will be invoked, so PositionChanged doesn't remember my previous position. Is it truth? Then PositionChanged event has no sense in BackgroundAgent, or? If I want to upgrade my position every 100m I have to save previous position and calculate distance with for example Haversine formula from previous and current positions?
Thanks man.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does GeoCoordinateWatcher.PositionChaged event work inside a periodic task?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871574/how-does-geocoordinatewatcher-positionchaged-event-work-inside-a-periodic-task)

Answer (score 0):

I think situation you've mentioned is the less important thing you should be worried about.

`GeoCoordinateWatcher` has much more serious limitations for Background Agent usage.

[Unsupported APIs for background agents for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> ***GeoCoordinateWatcher***
>
> This API, used for obtaining the geographic coordinates of the device,
>   is supported for use in background agents, but **it uses a cached
>   location value instead of real-time data**. The cached location value
>   is updated by the device every 15 minutes.

In Windows Phone 8 you're able to run location-tracking app in background to bypass that limitation: [Running location-tracking apps in the background for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), however, it's not available for Windows Phone 7.5.

Comment: It doesn't matter, that it uses cached location. Now I can't re-make my App for WP8.

Comment: It does matter, because you'll get the same location for 15 minutes, no matter how much will it really change.

Comment: No it doesn't. You imagine: object A is on position XX.XXX/YY.YYY, it moves 1km, after 15min new location is cached with new coordinates. If I will stay 1hour on same place I get the same coordinates. I've tested it. When I was moving I got always other position.